# Portable air conditioner question

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, cooling

I've picked a portable HVAC unit. It's a 2.6 KW 10,000 BTU model. The only way I will be able to vent it is by cutting a hole in one of the glass windows and and using the special fitting. I wanted to test the unit out in the mean time by just throwing the vent hose out of the door but of course the door is still open quite far like this. Is this not going to allow me to get an idea of how well the unit works with the door open so much or will it be drawing to much warm air in?

Comment: Are you sure it didn't come with a window mount? The hosed unit I used to have came with one and you could run both hoses (2 hose AC) out of the bottom of an open window

Comment: It does but I don't have a suitable window for where I want to place the unit. It is a small awning window but is to high from the floor so the hose won't reach it. The window underneath it is fixed but is the right height so I can a hole in the glass and use the special fitting in it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It's difficult for us to answer so many questions as a single question. Perhaps if you edit this down to a single primary question you'll get a good answer.